# Date not showing on highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

Why isn't the date on xAxis showing?

I can't seem to find anything wrong.

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
data: [
                [1104966000000, 1.94, 1.99, 1.91, 1.95],
                [1104793200000, 1.9, 1.95, 1.9, 1.9],
            ]
```

[jsfiddle as requested](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjorriemorrie/Usrca/1/)

Comment: please, show us your chart config or make jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle will be helfpul

Comment: @AndreyNelubin jsfiddle added in original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and [dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29)

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/Usrca/3/

```
xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y', this.value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That gives `invalid date`

Comment: Could you supply live demo ? in jsfiddle

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjorriemorrie/Usrca/2/) added with your suggestion

Comment: Awesome, thanks! AFAIK highstock has date as the xAxis by default; isn't that right?

Comment: Yes, excatly, highstock has default datetime xAxis.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33776/discussion-between-tjorriemorrie-and-sebastian-bochan)